# Does sentinel-2 provide Cloud Cover for every hours of a day?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to extract Cloud Cover hourly values for a 5-year period. The codes worked, but the csv file does not contain every hour in every day (I mean for a period of 5 years, I expect to have approximately  24*365*5 days). What is wrong with my codes?
I would be more than happy if anyone help me to fix the problem.
Sincerely.

```
var roi = ee.Geometry.Point(10.85, 35.98);

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
              .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2022-12-31')
              .select('QA60')
              .filterBounds(roi);
                     
function maskClouds(image) {
  var cloudyPixels = image.select('QA60').bitwiseAnd(1 << 10).eq(0);
  return image.updateMask(cloudyPixels);
}

var maskedDataset = dataset.map(maskClouds);

var hourlyMean = maskedDataset.map(function(image) {
  var date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start'));
  var mean = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: 1000,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  });
  return ee.Feature(null, {
    date: date.format('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),
    meanCloudCover: mean.get('QA60')
  });
});

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: hourlyMean,
  description: 'cloud_cover',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

I am trying to extract Cloud Cover hourly values for a 5-year period. The codes worked, but the csv file does not contain every hour in every day (I mean for a period of 5 years, I expect to have approximately  24*365*5 days). What is wrong with my codes?
I would be more than happy if anyone help me to fix the problem.
Sincerely.